# Can a SafeFrame render inside another SafeFrame?

Tags: iframe, google-dfp, google-publisher-tag

I am trying to understand if I can load a safeFrame inside another safeFrame. For example with Google Ad Manager (GAM) the gpt tag now serve ads within their own safeFrame, however if I am creating another safeFrame inside which I want to load the GPT ads the result is that ads not rendering. I am able to see gpt rendering only hosted ads (i.e. creatives that are directly uploaded in GAM and not serving and 3P creative hosted inside GAM). I tried deactivating "serve into safeFrame" manually for many 3P creatives but looks like its not working

So is this something that safeFrame will not work inside another safeFrame or can this be resolved using safeFrame API?

Comment: you sure your 3P creative were live when you tested it ? It it works with hosted creative it should work with 3P ones... Do you have a test page ?